# Xcode localization: Base concept without redundancy

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, localization

I am a little confused about the implementation of localization in Xcode. I know that I can provide as many languages as I want by creating the appropriate XY.Iproj folders and inserting the .strings and Localizable.strings files into them. This all happens automatically with Xcode.

Unfortunately I have problems understanding the Base concept. As I understood it so far, the development language is to be used there. In my case this is English, so should I write in the storyboard and XIB files as text directly in English? For example the headline (a label) of the settings page with the content "Settings"?

But why do I have also the .strings file with the translation into English? That would be redundant, because I have already entered English text directly in the Base file and the .strings file contains the same text again.

Or should the storyboard and XIB files only have identifiers like "settings_page_headline" as content for labels? But that's nonsense, because these labels are good for nothing...

Or can I completely delete the .strings for the English translation if I have already inserted the English content in the storyboard and XIB files?

I hope you can enlighten me a bit. Of course I have read the documentation of Apple, there my problem of understanding is not discussed as much as I need to understand it.

Main.storyboard (Base) and Main.strings (English) contain the same content:

[image: Main.storyboard and Main.strings (English) contain the same content]

Content of the Main.storyboard (Base):
[image: Content of the Main.storyboard (Base)]

Content of the Main.strings (English):

```
"tos-eB-aJc.title" = "Send Feedback";
"S56-oM-eis.title" = "Rate this App";
```

Answer (score 0):

From Apple documentation:
Xcode creates a Base.lproj folder in your project folder and adds to it the resource files you select. Xcode creates a language folder for the development language but only adds resources that need translation to the folder. For example, if you select English as the development language, Xcode inserts the resource file in the Base.lproj project folder but not the en.lproj folder because the resource is already in English.
link: [InternationalizingYourUserInterface](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/InternationalizingYourUserInterface/InternationalizingYourUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH3-SW2)

As I understand it, this was done to optimize the import of localization files. Also you can not localize some .xib . If you want to understand how, by what logic and in what order the localization files are loading, read this document from Apple: [LocalizingYourApp](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW1)

Comment: No, Apple states that the default language is the language stored at `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`. That is English for me. If I do not offer Italian, English is used (because `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`), which is stored in Main.strings (English) in en.Iproj folder. The content from the Base Storyboard is therefore not used again. So I could write "blaahhh" in every text field in the Base-Storyboard... I don't understand what the Base is for. It takes all texts from <storyboard/xib>.strings. And even if I don't support the desired language, Base is not used, but en.lproj... I don't understand.

Comment: I hastened to answer. It turned out to be much more complicated. I changed it.

Comment: Thanks for your change. So as I understand it now, can I delete the en.Iproj folder since my development language is already English? In the file Main.storyboard I will add the English text directly and only for further translations I will create XY.Iproj folders with the <storyboard/xib>.strings files? In relation to my image in the question I would have to remove Main.strings (English), so that I only have Base (=> English) and German?